# Parsing the headers of sequence file

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell, unix

I have a multiple sequence file as

```
>abc|d017961
sequence1......

>cdf|rhtdm9
sequence2......

>ijm|smthr12
sequence3......

>abc|d011wejr
sequence4......

>stg|eethwe77
sequence5......
```

I want to edit the file and want the result file as

```
>abc_ABC__d017961
sequence1......

>cdf_CDF__rhtdm9
sequence2......

>ijm_IJM__smthr12
sequence3......

>abc_ABC__d011wejr
sequence4......

>stg_STG__eethwe77
sequence5......
```

Thanks!

Comment: I assume this is how your headers look, sam. If not, feel free to change it back.

Comment: Cross-posted in [stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92291/parsing-the-headers-of-sequence-file). Please avoid cross-posting.

Comment: This question has been cross-posted and answered at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92291/parsing-the-headers-of-sequence-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/ (\w+) \| /$1_\U$1\E__/x' file
```

or

```
perl -lpe '$_ = "$1_\U$1\E__$2" if / (\w+) \| (\w+)/x' file
```

Comment: When using a capture and a concatenation with captured variables, you might consider using the `s///` operator instead.

Comment: Now I need to change the file

>xbc_ABC__d017961 word task kite
sequence1......

>df_CDF__rhtdm9 word task kite
sequence2......

to the result file

>abc|d017961
sequence1......

>cdf|rhtdm9
sequence2......

Comment: @sam `perl -pe 's/ \w+? ([A-Z]+) __ /\L$1|/x' file`

Answer (score 1):

You can define the input field separator (FS) to be `|`, the output field separator (OFS) to be `_` and then use the `toupper()` function.

All together:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="_"; FS="\|"}{print $1,toupper($1),OFS,$2}' file
abc_ABC___d017961 sequence1......
cdf_CDF___rhtdm9 sequence2......
ijm_IJM___smthr12 sequence3......
abc_ABC___d011wejr sequence4......
stg_STG___eethwe77 sequence5......
```